# Enable Opera Turbo in Selenium Opera Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

I need to enable Opera (*34.0.2036.25*) Turbo mode in an instance of Opera Webdriver.

I found preferences file with JSON inside:
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\preferences`

```
"turbo": {
        "client_id": "86161eba4fe344be368c664164a0692d9d7d6d367e2e712e49321dee0ea4351e",
        "enabled": true,
        "show_learn_more": false
    }
```

When I change `enable:`  from `false` to `true` and run Opera manually it starts in Turbo mode.

Selenium webdriver opens Opera with some virtual default profile, and obviously Turbo mode is turned off.

I tried this code:

```
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();

options.AddUserProfilePreference("turbo.enabled", true);

OperaDriver driver = new OperaDriver(options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Besides `turbo.enabled, true` I tried hundreds of different ways feed this parameter to `AddUserProfilePreference` method but Opera never started in Turbo mode.

I found temporary profile and preferences file located at:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8248_11147

there is no "enabled": true there obviously. So the question is how to force Opera to add this option to temp profile

```
"turbo": {
    "client_id": "34e3abeca0944cd655ee41e9aa1a87d58bc5605e319f56b6c6de983f7fcf668e"
}
```